# Dynamic update of SSL property of Kafka is not working

Tags: java, security, apache-kafka, tls1.2, mtls

For mutualTLS `"ssl.client.auth"` should be set to `"required"`. So, if we are trying to do the dynamic update using the below command

```
sh /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:28104 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 117373 **--alter --add-config listener.name.app.ssl.client.auth=required
```

Completed updating config for broker 117373.

```
sh /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:28104 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 117373 --describe
```

Dynamic configs for broker 117373 are:

```
 listener.name.app.ssl.client.auth=required sensitive=false synonyms={DYNAMIC_BROKER_CONFIG:listener.name.app.ssl.client.auth=required, STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:ssl.client.auth=none, DEFAULT_CONFIG:ssl.client.auth=none}
```

Dynamic command execution is success but in captured tcpdump(pcap) "Certificate Request" is not sent from Server below
[image]

But if we alter manually and restart Kafka we can see "Certificate Request" from Server in tcpdump.

Please help in resolving the dynamic update of altering "ssl.client.auth=Required"